# Collision Detection problem with loop order

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-engine

I'm having a problem not with the collision detection itself, but with the check order loop.

For the detection of the collisions I'm using AABB.

Visual representation for reference:
https://i.imgur.com/7SaeUjX.png

Scenario 1:

- I have three **square** objects; [player], [enemy1] and [enemy2].
- [enemy1] and [enemy2] are close to each other horizontally and the **[player] is above [enemy1]**.
- The player then starts moving with **DownArrow + RightArrow** constantly.
- So now, the [player] is over [enemy1] and [enemy 2] going right.
- Because the first element to be checked is [enemy1], the collision system corrects the y position of the [player] and because the right is not considered to be colliding, it can go right.
- RESULT: all good. The [player] can keep going on to the right without problem.

Scenario 2:

- I have three **square** objects; player, enemy1 and enemy2.
- [enemy1] and [enemy2] are close to each other horizontally and the **[player] is above [enemy2]**.
- The player then starts moving with **DownArrow + LeftArrow** constantly.
- So now, the [player] is over [enemy2] and [enemy 1] going left.
- Because the first element to be checked is [enemy1], the collision system corrects the y position, **and the x position** of the [player] and, of course, [enemy2] collision aren't important at this point.
- RESULT: of course, [player] gets blocked by [enemy1] and can not keep going left.

Explanation of the problem that I'm having in Scenario 2:

The problem lies in the check order of the collisions. The loop starts checking if the player cololides with [enemy1] directly because is the first to be checked, so the [player], of course, detects that is colliding with [enemy1] and solves the 2 collisions giving the bad result.

If you change the order of the list, starting from [enemy2], of course the problem comes in the other way around.

**What should I do to avoid this situation**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after looking and thinking for a solution, I ended up with this:

My collider manager now works this way (3 steps):

- Finds the overlaps
- Colects the info of the collision
- Sorts the collisions by overlaping area (collected in the info) and resolutes

So, the main difference now, is that I first analyze all the overlaps/collisions, and after that I treat them, in this case sorting by overlaping area

I hope that helps

Comment: Another option may be to sort by how far away the midpoint of the two colliding objects are.

Comment: That was my first strategy, but, if your objects has different sizes that won't work. For instance, in the second case in my example, if the [enemy2] was wider, then the distance to it would be more than the distance to [enemy1] and you would have the same result as starting the loop from [enemy1].